# How to remember the purpose of specific Terminal tabs?

Tags: macos, command-line, bash, terminal.app, multitasking

I always have multiple Terminal tabs open, each with a different purpose. I want to remind myself what that purpose is by echoing something (stored in a variable) whenever that tab becomes idle. (By idle, I mean that the command prompt is displayed with no command being run in a certain amount of time.)

Is this possible?

Note: Not a duplicate of [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/638357/execute-a-command-if-linux-is-idle-for-5-minutes), because that talks about running commands if the whole system becomes idle/the user is away from the computer.

Comment: Doesn't your terminal emulator allow you to rename tabs?

Comment: Whoa, is that a thing? I’ll check that in the morning, thanks!

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Thanks for showing me something new about my mac! Want to write an answer?

Comment: Not really, because my idea doesn't really answer the current question (which I read "how to run a command if a terminal tab is idle?"). Compare [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310). Besides, I don't really know how to rename a tab in `terminal.app`. You should know this now, so please *you* write an answer. You should also change ([edit]) the title of the question to something like "how to remind myself what the purpose of a certain terminal tab is?" The idea of running a command may stay in the question body, but the title should reflect the root problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @KamilMaciorowsky's idea in the comments, I was able to discover that Terminal tabs can be given names by showing the tab inspector and editing the title (shortcut: <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>I</kbd>).

This replaces the directory and current command at the tab bar at the top of the window with the text you type in.